# match an array with a given set of arrays

Tags: algorithms, arrays, equality

We have a set of 24 distinct arrays, each array has 36 elements and each element can have one of 13 possible values.

Then we're given an array X (this array is certainly part of our set) and we have to find to which array of our set it corresponds to.

Of course, we can check all 36 elements of X against each of 36 elements of our 24 arrays and find out with which it corresponds to.

I'm trying to reduce this number of 36 comparisons.

My naive approach is something like this:

- Take all possible subsets of 0..35, except the empty subset.
  Each of this subsets denotes which elements we should compare.
- Use each of this subsets with input all the 24 arrays of our given set and check which of these subsets produce as output the given set of our 24 arrays, these are valid subsets.
- From these valid subsets, the one with the fewer elements is our solution.

Unfortunately, all possible subsets of 0..35 excluding the empty subset is $2^{36}-1$

I was wondering if there could be another approach to the problem.

Many different arrays X will be matched against the given set of 24 arrays so any preprocessing of the 24 arrays is really worth the effort.

User JarkkoL suggested to precompute CRC32 of the set of the given arrays and then compare with the CRC32 of the array X.

Still, I'm wondering if there's a smart way not to calculate CRC32 for the whole array. I'm looking for the smallest possible number of elements for which I should compute it.

Comment: Do you have to do this once only, for a single array X, or do you have to repeat the performance for many successive values of X. In other words, is it worth preprocessing your 24 arrays ot speed up the matches, the preprocessing being amortized on many matches.

Comment: @babou Yes, preprocessing them is really worth the effort.

Comment: Welcome! Could you edit your question to include the information that you're going to be matching many inputs against your data? Comments are supposed to be just temporary and people shouldn't have to read them to figure out what the question is. Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a requirement to use only comparisons?  Seems like the obvious approach would be to use a hash table: compute a hash on the entire array (CRC32 is one example of a hash function), and use that as the key into a hash table.  This will make lookups very fast, as fast as hashing the array.

Comment: @D.W. Since using comparisons will be faster than hashing, I'm looking for comparisons only solution.

Comment: I realized that the smallish values given for this problem tend to
suggest solutions that do not generalize too well for large values.
So I added to my answer a better algorithm that should deal
effectively with large values of the parameters (though I only hint at
what should be done when the number $v$ of values is large).
Unfortunately I do not have time to rewrite the whole answer right
now, so I added that as a new better solution. I will do a cleaner
rewrite later. The very last suggestion, when $v$ is large, is
probably the best. The funcrion $\phi$ can be done with perfect hashing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $s$ be the size of an array (36 in your example), $v$ the number
of possible values (here 13) of each element, $n$ the numbers of
reference arrays (here 24), i.e., the size of the set $S=\{A_i \mid i\in[1..n]\}$ of arrays.

I am assuming that the cost for preprocessing the arrays does not
matter. Else, you can alsways simplify the procedure below, as long as
you do it well enough no to exceed the worst case time complexity
$O(n)$.

Ideally you want to get a balanced binary tree of test for
identification so that you get your answer in $\lceil \log_2 n \rceil$
tests, i.e. 5 tests at most with the given figures. In other words,
you are looking for 5 bits of information, that allow you to
discriminate between your $n=24$ arrays.

For that you would need a criterion, testable in one comparison,
that can cut approximately in two any given set of arrays, so that if
$n_1$ and $n_2$ are the sizes of the 2 subsets, $\lfloor \log_2 n_1
\rfloor = \lfloor \log_2 n_2 \rfloor$.

However, that is not always possible. A worst case example is, when
array $A_i$ contains only $0$, except for  element $A_i[i]$ that
contains $1$. Then the only way to identify $X$ in the reference set is
to scan the elements of $X$ to find which has value $1$. This has
complexity $O(n)$

So you you know complexity can be as bad as that, when an index will
discriminate at best one array. Of cours, in general, you have to
analyse the set of arrays to determine which indices you have to look
at.

However, if the set of arrays permit, you can do better, as indicated
above. For each index $i$ for the arrays, you try to identify a simple
test $T_i$ that will partition the set $S$ of arrays in two subsets $S_1$ and $S_2$ of nearly
equal sizes: $n_1$ and $n_2$, such that $|n_1-n_2|$ is minimal (this
is a bit stronger than the condition above, but the idea is to keep
some slack on each half for future partitions). You do that for each index
$i\in[1..s]$, and you keep the index $i_0$ that gives the minimal
difference $|n_1-n_2|$.  Of course, you can stop as soon as you have a
difference that is less than $2$, or possibly as soon as $\lfloor
\log_2 n_1 \rfloor = \lfloor \log_2 n_2 \rfloor$ (the choice is purely
heuristic). You can even stop earlier if you are not too worried about getting the fastest test tree.

Now for index $i_0$ you have a test $T_{i_0}$ that partitions your set $S$
of arrays into two disjoint subsets $S_1$ and $S_2$ of respective
sizes $n_1$ and $n_2$, on the basis of the values at index $i_0$.

This will be the first test you apply to a new array $X$ to identify
it in the set $S$. This test will tell you whether it is in $S_1$ or
$S_2$. Then you know that your identification of X will take at most
$1+\max(n_1,n_2)$ steps.

Then you pursue the construction of your balanced tree, on each of the
two subsets $S_1$ and $S_2$, and with some luck you can approach the
optimal complexity $O(\log_2 n)$. No garantee given, since a bad set
of arrays can impose the maximum complexity $O(n)$, with the forced
reading of, on average, n/2 elements of $X$.

But there is still one very important detail that is missing. **What
kind of test is to be used**. The answer is: any kind that is easy
enough to count as one step. So I guess a primality test that
partitions arrays into those with prime integer at index $i$ and those
with non-prime at index $i$ is *not a good idea*.

Suggestions are: testing if the $A_j[i]$ is equal to a given value, or
whether it is greater than some value, or whether $A_j[i] \mod p = r$
for two values $p$ and $r$. Just use your imagination, if there is a need
for it. This can all be mechanized, tried automatically, but with a
computation cost. What you should do depends on how much speeding up
recognition by thorough preprocessing is essential for you.

### A faster solution for large values of $n$, assuming $v$ remains small.

Actually, though the worst case $O(n)$ cannot be improved, one can do
better than the first solution I propose above, assuming $v$ remains small.

The idea is that one does not need to use binary tree.  With more
branching, one can get even faster to the answer.

For that purpose, we need to build a function $\phi$ that maps the $v$
values used into the integer range $[1..v]$. This can be done by
hashing or by other means. Then *we can assume without loss of
generality that the values used are the integer in $[1..v]$.*

Then one could find a minimal set $I$ of indices for the arrays, so that
for any pair of arrays $A_j$ and $A_k$ there is an index $i\in I$ such
that $A_j[i] \neq A_k[i]$. Then, for any array $X$ known to be equal
to an array $A_h\in S$, we can identify $A_h$ by looking only at the
values for the indices in $I$. One could then build a decision tree
based on these indices considered in succession.

However, finding such a minimal set of indices may be difficult (I did
not look into its complexity), and there may be better solutions, by
using independent indices for the different nodes on a given level of
the decision tree.

So we can probably get an even faster result by proceeding as
follow. Choose a first index $i_0$ such that the $p$ different values
for that index partition the set $S$ of arrays into $p$ subsets $S_x$
for $x\in [1..p]$. Depending on whether you try to reduce the average
cost or the maximum cost, you may try to choose $i_0$ so as to
maximize $p$, or to minimize the maximum size of the subsets $S_x$
(though this is heuristic). These $p$ subsets are the daughters of the root in the decision tree being built.

Then you repeat this operation for each subset, finding independently
for each subset $S_x$ a new index $i_{x,1}$, so as to further
partition the subset.

You repeat the operation until you reach the leaves which correspond
to singleton sets, i.e., a specific array in $S$.

You get a widely branching decision tree, where each non-leaf node
(actually corresponding to a subset of arrays) is labeled by an index,
each branch is labeled by a value found for that index, and each leaf
is labeled by an array in $S$. This tree must be implemented so that
each branch can be accessed in one step by direct indexation.

Then, given an array $X$, you read its value at the index $i_0$
labeling the root, and use this value as $\phi(X[i_0])$ to access by
indexation the next node in the tree. Then you repeat the step until
you reach a leaf.

**When $v$ is large**, the algorithm has to be adapted by using a
different function $\phi$ at each node.

Comment: Agreed, good solution.  This is closely related to the problem of building a decision tree (see, e.g., the ID3 algorithm in machine learning, which could be applied here).

Answer (score 1):

You could calculate something like crc32 of the arrays and compare them with the crc32 of the new array. If the crc32's of the arrays match then you can do further check if the elements actually match (in case there is crc32 collision, which is very rare). If you know the new array exists in the set, you could select crc32 seed value which avoids the crc32 collisions, so once you find the crc32 match you can be sure it's the correct one without comparing the elements at all (just test max 24 ints). You could try something more lightweight than crc32 too if that's a performance issue.

If you would really want to push this, you could then sort the arrays by the checksum value and find the matching checksum with binary search, thus cutting the number of comparisons to log2(24)=5. Maybe not worth it for such a small amount of arrays though.

Comment: crc32 of the whole array or parts of it? I'm really interested if parts of the array (specific elements) could be used.

Comment: What ever method gives you unique checksums across all the arrays. If only crc32ing the first element gives unique checksum for all the 24 arrays then you only need to crc32 that. Since you can preprocess the arrays, you can find this in the preprocess step. Btw, this assumes that the elements in the arrays are in the same order. You didn't mention if this is the case, but I assume so since you said  comparing the arrays is O(n)

Comment: well, that's what I'm looking for, a smart way to know which elements should I crc32 to get unique results, they could be the first 5 elements, or the first 2 and some in the middle, etc. Updating my question to reflect this

Comment: Just start by calculating crc32 for the first element, if it's unique for all arrays then that's it. If not then calculate it for the first 2 elements, and so on. You could do something simplier than crc32 too, like `unsigned checksum=0; for(unsigned i=0; i<36; ++i) checksum+=array[i]^123;`

Comment: Surely calculating crc32 for the first element, then for first 2 elements, etc until no collision will give a solution but it will miss possible, maybe smaller in number of elements, solutions that are not in the form of consecutive elements from the start of the array.

Comment: What kind of performance requirements you have exactly? Is it worth to add complexity to the algorithm for potentially neglible gain?

Comment: At my specific case, I've managed through trial and error to reduce the number of elements from 36 to 8 which resulted in about 40% less execution time.

Comment: Ok, I just want to make sure that you do realize that you don't have to calculate crc32 for the other arrays but only for the new array when comparing, right?